# WP8.1 : opening and reading txt files

Tags: database, windows-phone-8.1

I have a quite simple problem that I can't solve though. I've built an app for windows that I would like to port on WP8.1. It is very basic : I have a .txt file (2 columns) containing questions and answers picked randomly.

My question is very simple: what would be the "best", or at least easiest way of interacting with this file ?

I found a tutorial describing the use of Windows.Storage namespace. I have code such as :

```
async Task<int> getHighScore()
    {
        Uri highscoreFileLoc = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Highscore.txt");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(highscoreFileLoc);
        var highscore = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        int HighScore;
        int.TryParse(highscore, out HighScore);
        return HighScore;
    }
```

This works fine, I can fetch the data in the txt file. It works in this very simple example, but in a larger application I am very confused with await/async; my app runs but gets stuck. So I am looking for an easier way.

I found the System.IO.IsolatedStorage namespace ... but found out that it is not working with the latest WP8.1. The only option is

```
using System.IO.Compression;
```

Going further, I found a tutorial on LINQ and databases (on MSDN).. however, it seemed a bit complicated to use for such an easy task.

Should I go on with the "StorageFile way" of doing, or switch to databases ? Or is there an even easier way ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no isolated storage on WinRT as it's a Silverlight legacy, WinRT instead uses `Windows.Storage` namespace. Compression is not an option as it doesn't relate to storing data.

The freezes are caused by blocking the UI thread. Review your code, there might be some blocking operations.

And here's one tip. As I've seen in your code, you store high score in the package's installation folder. I know, it's really easy to just drag'n'drop file there, but you won't be able to change it or remove, as each file in the app's folder is read-only for the sandboxed applications.

Consider using `ms-appdata://` scheme to store files in AppData folder.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. I've went back to a previous version where I do not call a file but rather define a few questions/answers directly in my main programm and everything's fine. When I add async/await, something goes wrong. So, you're right the freeze is indeed not related to Windows.Storage alone. I'm too confused to understand where the "bug" is, so I'll start over and add file reading methods one by one.